# Wordpress photos not aligning with text

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, alignment

I am using an underscores template theme with WordPress and cannot seem to align my images with my text.

[Here is the link I am looking at](http://rachelcrogala.com/work/ohiowomen/).
I am trying to align the first image with the "Overview" heading and following paragraph. The current image has this code:

```
img.alignleft {

    float: left;

    margin: 1em 1em 1em 0;
}
```

but the paragraph is still not aligning with it. Could someone please explain to me why this is not working?

Comment: if you are about  image named `ohio women`, then it's aligned with headline `overview`.

Comment: In the css`* {overflow-x:hidden;}` and `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {clear:both;}` prevent the float from working, remove them and see.

Comment: @Stickers you were exactly right, taking out both these things automatically fixed the alignment. Thank you so much!